# ceiling fan with a light

Tags: ceiling-fan

when changing a defective fan I found out that because only 2 wire 
cables were used, they have used the ground as the third wire to supply
the light. Is this legal and safe? This is in a condo in Florida

Comment: AGAIN?!  Can you post photos of the boxes please?  This crap's getting old...

Comment: Wow, that's the second time this question has been asked in a week.  Any more and it might need to go on the how to ask page.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I'd hope to christ they used that ground conductor as the neutral and the two insulated ones as hots, which is probable because you're not dead.

But no.  It's not safe what they did. Undo it, and use the pullchains, or use a wireless controller

Comment: Yeah -- powerline-comms controlers such as the Lutron Maestro are also an option...